# How to determine container type based on user input

Tags: c++, class, data-structures

For one of my school projects, I'm implementing a class which holds two separate containers, which are supposed to be stacks or queues based on which container the user specifies. My question is, is it possible to create two private member containers - let's call them container1 and container2 - and specify whether each is respectively a stack or a queue? (at construction)

Comment: Are these [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)?

Comment: Is the type of each container determined at compile time or run-time?

Comment: yes it's from the standard language

Comment: at runtime also

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable option, Patrick. The hard part will be making an interface that conceals the differences between the two from the user. You'd pretty much only be able to expose get, push, and pop  methods.

Comment: basically they'd run ./main.exe -container1 <stack|queue>, and when the class is created it would chose the type based on the command line input

Comment: Adding to @user4581301, you can make an interface over `std::stack` and `std::queue` and use a bit of inheritance to achieve what you want. Or if possible just do some if/else blocks and call whatever functions you need to on the stack/queue separately.

Comment: I was considering using a deque to represent both, and just implementing functions that will work with the deque like a stack or queue, but I think there's got to be a better way.

Comment: I'm familiar with inheritance but I don't really understand how id do that Brady.

Comment: Avoid inheriting directly from Standard Library classes. Few are intended for it. In general prefer [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), ie make classes that contain stuff, rather than classes that inherit stuff. Also keep an eye on the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle) when using inheritance.

Comment: @PatrickM Create 2 simple classes that contain a `std::stack` or `std::queue`. Both of these inherit from something like `Container` that has `push`, `pop`, and `get` methods. At run-time, check what the user wants and allocate either of the 2 classes into a `Container*`.

Comment: @PatrickM `std::stack` uses a `deque` under the hood (by default) to begin with, so I don't see anything wrong with using a `deque` for both containers.

Comment: Using a single `deque` and changing how the interface behaves behind the scenes is an even better approach.

Answer (score 0):

With template, you might have

```
template <typename Container1, typename Container2>
class MyClass
{
public:
    // ....
private:
    Container1 c1;
    Container2 c2;
};

// Dispatch functions for non uniform code
template <typename T> void do_job_specific(std::stack<T>& s) {/*..*/}
template <typename T> void do_job_specific(std::queue<T>& d) {/*..*/}

// Common code
template <typename Container> void do_job_common(Container& d) {/*..*/}
```

and for main job

```
template <typename T> // would be MyClass<C1, C2>
void do_job()
{
    T myClass;
    // ...
}

enum class EContainer { Stack, Queue};

void dispatch_job(EContainer e1, EContainer e2)
{
    using T1 = std::stack<int>;
    using T2 = std::queue<int>;
    if (e1 == EContainer::Stack) {
        if (e2 == EContainer::Stack)) {
            do_job<std::stack<T1, T1>>();
        } else {
            do_job<std::stack<T1, T2>>();
        }
    } else {
        if (e2 == EContainer::Stack)) {
            do_job<std::stack<T2, T1>>();
        } else {
            do_job<std::stack<T2, T2>>();
        }
    } 
}
```

Now `main` just have to call the method with selected enum from user.